# How can I delay the video feed on my screen?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, gpu

I have Bluetooth headphones, quite decent but with PC they jave a lipsync issue, I can overcome this with downloaded media by delaying audio by preferred amount.

Can I do this with GPUs feed to the monitor systemwide, or just adjust the audio or any suitable fix for browser-wide or Netflix or YouTube.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess the answer would be no. There may be hardware, or discrete software/hardware solutions that perform this function, but relying simply on resources of the computer itself you'd be instructing the video system to store vast quantities of video data, just holding on to it, for extended periods of time, far longer than its designed to handle.

Basically, you'd be asking your computer to do something it was designed NOT to do.

I may be wrong, but I don't think I am.

Comment: What about audio delay by -0.2 seconds it somehow sounds more doable to me.

Comment: I'd imagine that it is more doable as well.